# how to pass Dynamic Data to a Azure Bot so that a single Bot behave according to the data Feeded

Tags: .net, json, botframework, docx

I have many Courses/Packages and on Course level I want to Open Azure Bot and Feed the data dynamically So that on each Course Level/Package the Chat will behave according to the Data Feeded, is it Possible to To with Direct Line API to pass Data dynamically in the Form of a File ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example here, of how to receive a file in a bot: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-ReceiveAttachment

This page explains how to upload attachments using the rest api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-send-activity#upload-attachments

The Direct Line Client provided in this library can also be used to upload attachments:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine